# Extracting MatConvnet model weights

Tags: c++, opencv, machine-learning, caffe, matconvnet

I am currently developing an application for facial recognition.

The algorithms are implemented and trained using the MatConvnet library (http://www.vlfeat.org/matconvnet/). At the end, I have a Network (.mat file) which looks like that:
[image]

[image]

I would like to know if it were possible to extract the weights of the Network using its .mat file, write them in a XML file and read them with Caffe C++. I would like to reuse them in Caffe C++ in order to do some testing and hardware implementation. Is there an efficient and practical way to proceed so ?

Thank you for very much for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a conversion script that converts matconvnet models to caffe models [here](https://github.com/zoharby/matconvnet/blob/master/utils/convert_matconvnet_caffe.m) which you may find useful.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. It has helped me a lot :)

Answer (score 2):

The layer whose parameters you'd like to store, must be set as 'precious'. In net.var you can access the parameters and write them.

Comment: Thanks h612 for your answer !

Answer (score 1):

You can't use weights of the trained Network by matconvnet for caffe. You can merely import your model from matconvnet to caffe.(https://github.com/vlfeat/matconvnet/blob/4ce2871ec55f0d7deed1683eb5bd77a8a19a50cd/utils/import-caffe.py). But this script does not support all layers and you may have difficulties in employing it. 
The best way is to define your caffe prototxt in python as the matconvnet model.

Comment: There is already an accepted answer, so OP's problem has been solved.